# How to integrate blog software into an aspx page in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, blogs, blog-engine

I was given a task to integrate a blog software to a sample.aspx page in asp.net website.

I didn't understand what does it mean.

If i install a blog software on my system then how can i integrate to an aspx page web 
application.
I'm confused at this step.
Please anybody help.

Thanks

**update**
I installed BlogEngine.Net on my system, but when i browse it opens as a separate website. I don't want in this way.

What I want is there is a page sample.aspx in my asp.net application and a navigation link for this page on menu.So when click on this link , this page will open and blog software should run on this page.

Which blog software will be best suited for this condition?

Comment: I would ask the client/stakeholder exactly what they mean. because you are correct, what they are asking can be interpreted many different ways.

Comment: thanks Json for your reply.I'll ask client the same.

Comment: I installed BlogEngine.Net on my system but when i browse it opens as a separate website.I don't want in this way.What i want is there is a page sample.aspx in my asp.net application and a navigation link for this page on menu.So when click on this link , this page will open and blog software should run on this page.Which blog software will be best suited for this condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option, if it's even an option at all, is to have the website and blog engine be separate urls, but use the same theme across both the site and the blog. this way, the user won't really be able to tell the difference other than the url changed. (and how many people really look at the url anymore?)

but trying to put the blog egine "in" the web site doesn't make much sense.